# How do i give an alias to results in a column gridview. c# adio.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have SQL database using C#. I'm populating a `GridView`.

I would like to give an alias for a column depending on condition. So for example, if the SQL result in my column says `"order not placed"` I would like to change it to `"Awaiting confirmation"` and if it says `"Emailed"` I want to alias it to say `"order confirmed for collection"`.

How do I do this in the C# code?

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Current Status");
    table.Columns.Add("ID");
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        //linking column with data
        DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
        dataRow["Current Status"] = rdr["Current Status"];
        dataRow["ID"] = rdr["ID_MSG_SLIP"];
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is adio.net? Google doesn't seem to know.

Comment: When you say 'alias' do you mean the name of the column, or do you mean you want the *value* to be dynamic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET

Comment: The value to be changed

Comment: Doing it in C# would require us to know what your code looks like for populating the grid view... so you should include that

Comment: you have to perform it in `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: You don't want a column alias but you want to change the value for a value in a record according to the original value. Otherwise it doesn't make sense because a column contains multiple values.

Comment: alright how would i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looping through the result you can easily evaluate the current status and then change it based on your logic.

I assume that "Current Status" is the column you are referring to, so this should work:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    string currentStatus = (string)rdr["Current Status"];
    if(currentStatus == "Emailed")
        currentStatus = "order confirmed for collection";
    else if(currentStatus == "order not placed")
        currentStatus = "Awaiting confirmation";

    DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
    dataRow["Current Status"] = currentStatus;
    dataRow["ID"] = rdr["ID_MSG_SLIP"];
    table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

NOTE: You seem to have inconsistencies with your casing in the strings, you may need to review that in order to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `TemplateField` Code in your GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Durum">
<ItemTemplate>

    // Bind your column from database in Eval
    <asp:Label ID="lblSqlValue" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("sqlColumnName") %>'></asp:Label> 

    // this will show the Alias on the database column value
    <asp:Label ID="lblAlias" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string lblSqlValue = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSqlValue")).Text;
        Label lblAlias = e.Row.FindControl("lblAlias") as Label;

        if (lblSqlValue=="order not placed")
            lblAlias.Text = "Awaiting confirmation";
        else if(lblSqlValue=="Emailed")
            lblAlias.Text = "order confirmed for collection";
        else
            lblAlias.Text = "No Value";
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `OnRowDataBound` in GrindView like `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >`